# When doing an automated build on docker hub--with bitbucket repo--do I still need to include a "git pull" instruction in the dockerfile?

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile

I have a bitbucket repo that I connected to Docker Hub for automated build. I was wondering how to get the source files from the bitbucket repo into the docker build.

Do I still need to include an instruction in the Dockerfile for ADDing a folder, such as:

```
ADD python_model /home/condauser/tmp
```

Or should I use a git pull command to clone a repo into a directory in the docker image? I was not sure if this was automatically handled by the Docker Hub connection or not.

Answer (score 0):

The automated builds basically make a checkout of your repository, and build the Dockerfile that's in the repository. All you need to do is make sure that the Dockerfile adds the files that are needed to it, using `COPY` or `ADD`.